# Adding to values to a database in repl.it not working

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary, replit

I will go directly to the point; I'm having problems with accessing values in my Repl.it Database.
I made an entire class in another file to access the database, I'm able to print out and return values but can't add values to a list in the database.

**Here is my function (inside of a class) to add VIP members(discord) to the database:**

```
def add_vip(self, db_name, user_id):
  if db_name in db:

    # Check if user not already in DB
    if user_id not in db[db_name]["users_id"]:
        db[db_name]["users_id"].append(user_id)

        # Verify if user was added
        return (True, "User added!", db[db_name]["users_id"], type(db[db_name]["users_id"]))

    else:
        return (False, "User already exists!", "Error")

else:
    return (False, "Db does not exist or lengh of user_id below 18 digits!", "Error"
```

**The actual problem:** It prints out the debugging return, and it prints out "True, "User added" and all that etc.. but it does not actually add it to the list inside of that key."

I feel like this may be a really dumb mistake that I just can't identify... Anyways I'm seeking the gods of Stackoverflow for this, thank you.

*If you need more code just lmk and I'll send it!*

**This does not give me any errors**
That's why I did not post it here!

Comment: `db[db_name]["users_id"] = user_id` That code doesn't add to a list...

Comment: Actually I'm so sorry, its supposed to be .append(user_id)
Just edited it, that code was from me trying to just change values around to make it work.
I currently have it like it is up there: .append(user_id) which should work as db[db_name]["users_id"] is a list

Comment: Where is `db` defined?

Comment: Db is defined at the top:
from replit import db
a one liner giving to you by repl in the database section

Comment: How do you know the userid isn't being added?  Do you have some code that checks the database afterwards?  Show us that code.